# How can I use Intel Management Engine on Gigabyte motherboard?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, drivers, intel

How can I use Intel Management Engine on Gigabyte motherboard?

I installed it from official Gigabyte website in drivers section for my motherboard `Gigabyte X299 UD4` but no one executable appeared after installation:

[image]

But I can't connect to it. I can't setup it. And I can't even activate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon research, these are the system requirements for Intel Management Engine to run on your PC:

- Intel® Q57/H57/H55/P55 Express Chipset
- Mobile Intel® QM57/QS57/HM57/HM55/PM55 Express Chipsets
- Windows XP* 32-bit SP2 and higher
- Windows Vista* 32-bit and 64 bit, SP2 and higher
- Windows 7* 32-bit and 64-bit
- Microsoft* .NET framework 3.5 or higher
- Intel® Management Engine Interface (Intel® MEI) driver (if applicable for your system)
- You must also have administrator privileges or run the program as administrator
- NOTE: Always make sure to reboot after installation.

This all comes from their support page/FAQ regarding this software.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/software/chipset-software/000005974.html

Make sure you meet these requirements and if you still have issues you could try to contact their support.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/contact-support.html

Comment: It also depends on CPU. I think, my i7-7820X doesn't support it.